# Querying by attribute or related attribute with SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

My abstraction is: *Book* has only one *User* (as *author*), and a many to many relationship with *User* (as *collaborators*):

```
class UserBook(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'user_book'
    user_id = Column(String(512), ForeignKey('user.id'), primary_key=True)
    book_id = Column(String(512), ForeignKey('book.id'), primary_key=True)
    collaboration_type = Column(Integer, default=1)
    book = relationship('Book', back_populates='users')
    user = relationship('User', back_populates='books')


class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'user'

    id = Column(String(512), primary_key=True)
    books = relationship('UserBook', back_populates='user')


class Book(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'book'

    id = Column(String(512), primary_key=True)
    author = Column(String(512), ForeignKey('user.id'), nullable=False)
    collaborators = relationship('UserBook', back_populates='book')
    name = Column(String(512))
    description = Column(String(512), default='')
```

I'm looking to select all books where I'm an author **or** I'm a collaborator using SQLAlchemy declarative queries if possible.

I was able to make the join with collaborator, but I'm not sure how to **or** with the author filter.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`or_`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/sqlelement.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.or_) operator with your filter to get all the books where the current user is an author or a collaborator. For example:

```
from sqlalchemy import or_


curr_id = 'current_user_id'

session.query(Book).\
    outerjoin(UserBook).\
    filter(or_(Book.author == curr_id, UserBook.user_id == curr_id)).\
    all()
```